# Lazily evaluate monadic functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation

I can't seem to figure out a workaround for this issue i'm having.

I have something like this:

```
  getFilePathForDay :: Day -> IO (Maybe FilePath)

  getFilePathForDays date days = do
      files <- mapM getFilePathForDay $ iterate (addDays 1) date
      return . take days . catMaybes $ files
```

I am trying to get x amount of valid file paths where x is the number of days I want, but the above code just runs forever. I have ran into this problem before with monads and I was wondering if there is a workaround available for this issue I am having.

Thanks!

Comment: Why does this need to be in the IO monad at all? Are you testing for file existence? If so, can't that be done *after* generating the file paths?

Comment: @Robin Green: Perhaps Ratzes wants to find the first `n` existing files starting at a given date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code runs forever because you are trying to sequence an infinite number of side-effecting computations in your call to `mapM`.

Since you don't know ahead of time how many of these computations you will need to run (as indicated by your use of `catMaybes`), you will have to interleave the calls to `getFilePathForDay` with the rest of your computation. This could be done using `unsafeInterleaveIO`, but as the name suggests, this is not a recommended approach.

You could implement this manually as:

```
getFilePathForDays _ 0 = return []
getFilePathForDays date days = do
    mpath <- getFilePathForDay date
    case mpath of
        Just path -> (path :) <$> remaining (days-1)
        Nothing   -> remaining days
  where
    remaining days = getFilePathForDays (addDays 1 date) days
```

There is probably a more elegant way, but it's not coming to me right now :)

Comment: Generating a list by pattern matching on Maybes sounds like an unfold; maybe there's an elegant equivalent unfold expression?

Comment: @Dan: That was my initial thought as well, but it's not quite the trivial one. We want to keep going until we got a certain number of `Just`s, filtering out the `Nothing`s rather than stopping on the first `Nothing`.

Comment: @Dan: There are monadic sequencing unfolds floating around, yes, but in this case we need both an unfolding function (generating the paths) and a folding function (counting `Just`s and reading only as many as needed), both with side effects, that need to be interleaved in the right way. An elegant generalization certainly exists, but it probably has a cryptic name and is in the `category-extras` package.

Comment: It's really silly that we don't have an unfoldM somewhere in the standard libs.

Comment: There is one in [monad-loops](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-loops/0.3/doc/html/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v:unfoldM). But yeah, probably a nice candidate for base.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes lazy IO is the right approach. Since you have an infinite, lazy sequence of days, and you're sampling, lazily, some (dynamic) range from that sequence, we should also hit the filesystem only on demand.

This can be done with `unsafeInterleaveIO`:

```
import System.IO.Unsafe         ( unsafeInterleaveIO )

-- return a lazy list of filepaths, pull as many as you need
getFilePathForDays :: Day -> Int -> IO [FilePath]
getFilePathForDays date days = do

    let go (d:ds) = unsafeInterleaveIO $ do
                        f  <- getFilePathForDay d
                        fs <- go ds
                        return (f:fs)

    -- an infinite, lazy stream of filepaths
    fs <- go (iterate (addDays 1) date)

    return . take days . catMaybes $ fs
```

Where `go` returns a lazy stream of results, and we take as many as we need. Easy.

Comment: If you extracted out the lazy IO to a function like `lazyMapIO f (a:as) = unsafeInterleaveIO $ do b <- f a ; bs <- lazyMapIO f as ; return (b:bs)`, then Ratzes could just swap `lazyMapIO` in for `mapM` in their current code.

Comment: A `lazySequenceIO` would be awful handy in general, but of course it would never make it into base thanks to the (entirely correct, but still...) "Lazy IO is evil" mob, whom I am sympathetic with in every regard except that of the code I actually write :-)